# Name of line of slope 1 through the origin

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a name for the line that goes through the origin and has a slope of $1$? I would call those with $0$ and infinite slope the $x-$ and $y$-axes, and it seems like the slope $1$ case is basic enough it should have a name. Does it?

Comment: The line $y=x$ ? The bisector of the first and third quadrants?

Comment: It is the symmetry line for inverse functions...

Comment: There are infinitely many lines with zero and undefined slope -- not just the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: @symplectomorphic that go through the origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is (the graph of) the **identity function** $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Probably better to say it's the graph of the identity function (unless you're being really formal and defining a function as a set of ordered pairs, in which case it is its graph).

Answer (score 1):

Fourty-five degree line is a possibility- often used in economics.